# how to make my xl converted text in all lowercase and trimed in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, excel, text, trim, lowercase

I tried on converting my xl to json. Conversion is happening well, but though I have written code for conversion to lowercase and trim, its not happening. I am getting the output as below.. but I am expecting the output all in lowercase and trimmed..can someone help

```
   var exceltojson = require("xlsx-to-json");
          exceltojson(
              {
            input: "test.xlsx",
            output: 'test.txt', 
            sheet: "Sheet1",  

          }, function(err, result) 
          {
            if(err) 
            {
              console.error(err);
            }
          });
```

output:

```
[
  {
    Email: 'abc@123.com',
    'First Name': 'a',
    'Middle Name': 'b',
    'Last Name': 'c',
    'Address 1': 'd',
    'Address 2': 'lol',
    'Phone No': '123456789'
  },
  {
    Email: 'a@123.com',
    'First Name': 'g',
    'Middle Name': 'h',
    'Last Name': 'i',
    'Address 1': 'j',
    'Address 2': 'lol',
    'Phone No': '458745'
  }
]
```

I expect output like

```
[
  {
    email: 'abc@123.com',
    firstname: 'a',
    middlename: 'b',
    lastname: 'c',
    'address 1': 'd',
    'address 2': 'lol',
    phoneno: '123456789',
  },
  {
    email: 'a@123.com',
    firstname: 'g',
    middlename: 'h',
    lastname: 'i',
    address1: 'j',
    'address 2': 'lol',
    phoneno: '458745',
  },
];
```

Comment: Please post the conversion code that you have written.

Comment: above I have shared

Comment: this code converts xl to json, but don't do lowercase and trim

Comment: there are no option `trim` and `lowerCaseHeaders` where did you get that? from `result` you have to manually make it lowercase.

Comment: what you meant by doing manually

Comment: can I get some references?

Comment: okay. so to better understand console log the result that you are getting.

Comment: yeah I have added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library doesn't have any options such as trim/tolowercase. You have to do it manually.

```
const exceltojson = require('xlsx-to-json');
const fs = require('fs');
exceltojson({
    input: 'test.xlsx',
    // output: 'test.txt', Don't need output
    sheet: 'Sheet1'
  },
  function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      return;
    }
    const newResult = result.map(obj => {
      const newObj = Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc, key) => {
        const newKey = key.replace(/ /g, '').toLowerCase();
        acc[newKey] = obj[key];
        return acc;
      }, {});
      return newObj;
    });
    fs.writeFileSync('file.txt', JSON.stringify(newResult));
  }
);
```

Comment: how can I give the path..... I ran this code but got throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE(propName, ['string', 'Buffer', 'URL'], path);

Comment: fs.writeFileSync('file.txt', 'C:/users/Desktop', JSON.stringify(newResult));  ----still got error

Comment: that is wrong syntax. it will be s.writeFileSync('C:/users/Desktop/file.txt', JSON.stringify(newResult));